# Passing state from one React Component to another

Tags: javascript, reactjs, properties

I am very new to React (3 days of experience)

I want to pass a date from one component to another but this does not work for me.

**What I implemented so far:**

```
export class Kurse extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
}


numbers = ["21.02.2019", "02.05.2018", "13.03.2018", "04.07.2018", "05.08.2018"];
listItems = this.numbers.map((date) =>
  <p><Link to={{pathname: "/bookCourse/"+date}}><Button>{date}</Button></Link></p>
);
render() {
  return(
    <div>
      <h2>Wähle Deinen Wunschtermin</h2>
      {this.listItems}
    </div>
  );
 }
}
```

---

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact render = { () => <Home/>} />
          <Route path="/cityChoice" exact render = { () => <CityChoice/>} />
          <Route path="/kurse" exact render = { () => <Kurse/>}/>
          <Route path='/kjhkhkhkh-spezialisten' component={() => window.location = 'http://kjhkhkhkh-spezialisten.de'}/>
          <Route path='/bookCourse/:date' exact render = { () => <Form/>} />            
      </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

---

```
export class Form extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        vorname: '',
        nachname: '',
        email: '',
        telefon: '',
        refbeginn: 'nächstes Jahr',
        schulart: 'grundschule'
    };
}

...
...

return (
    <div id="form_container">
     {this.props.location.params.date}
...
...
```

**What I expected:**

I expected that the date variable is accessible from within the Form component.

**The actual result:**

TypeError: this.props.location is undefined

Comment: can you use [this](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/url-params)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should pass props to component to access it inside the component. in you case where you have mentioned

```
<Form location = "some value" />
```

this allows you to access location props in side the Form component using {this.props.location}.

Comment: Do you mean in the routing part?
<Route path='/bookCourse/:date' exact render = { () => <Form/ location =  date>} />
?

Comment: if you want to access the date in you path i mean from /bookCourse/:date, to access this variable you can directly use this.props.params.date. if you want to get date as separate prop then you can pass it in <Form location = {date} /> and you can use it by this.props.location

Comment: Ok. I chose to use option one (to pass it via Path in the URI).
Unfortunately it says still TypeError: this.props.params is undefined :-(

Comment: do a console log of this.props and see where exactly you are getting the value and use that path.

Comment: I did a console.log of this.props which resulted in an empty object { }.
I do not have a clue why it is empty.

Comment: Ah ... I am getting closer ...
<Route path='/bookCourse/:date' exact render = { (props) => <Form location={props}/>} />

gives me an object with

{…}
​
history: {…}
​​
action: "POP"
....
​​​
pathname: "/bookCourse/21.02.2019"
​​​
Now can I have only the date?

Comment: sorry for late, try with `<Route path='/bookCourse/:date' exact render = { (props) => <Form {...props} />} />` once and console this.props

you may get it under this.props.match.params.date